# How to give different marker for google map in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails2

**Controller.rb**

Rails 4.0 + gmaps4rails 2.0.3 + ruby 2.0.0
i want to change the marker image on the google map. if i am giveing "picture" => 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000', nothing is coming if any one have any idea how to do? please share
Thanks

```
Gmaps4rails.build_markers(object) do |user, marker|
   marker.lat user.latitude
   marker.lng user.longitude
   marker.infowindow user.location
   marker.picture({
   "picture" => 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000',
   "width" =>  '16',        
   "height" => '16'
   })
   marker.json({:title => user.title})
end
```

I am trying This one also but different marker is not coming any idea where i am wrong?

```
def CommonUtils.get_gmap_city_marker(object)
     Gmaps4rails.build_markers(object) do |user, marker|
         marker.lat user.latitude
         marker.lng user.longitude
         marker.infowindow user.location
         marker.picture({
            :picture => "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000", # up to you to pass the proper parameters in the url, I guess with a method from device
            :width   => 32,
            :height  => 32
            })
          marker.json({:title => user.title})
      end
  end
```

Comment: replace sizes with 32

Comment: @apneadiving can you review my code please?

Comment: code is good, works for me, change sizes

Comment: default marker is coming only..

Comment: cant tell what you do wrong, with size of 16 I get; https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/5fa0a285-b270-49ae-a41a-d1b7ca7c8aa0/5158cecb79397007ce106d5d59205d13

Comment: If i am changing the width and height also its not effecting the marker itself it is coming as usual default..

Comment: I guess you dont pass the proper variables, look at your dom

Comment: Any Idea Please Share ?

Comment: Do I owe you something? how dare you ask for ASAP answers? again, the code works perfectly, I tried it in an app of mine. The issue is somewhere on your side and I cant guess.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers) you have to use

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
      {
       "picture" => "/images/#{name}.png",
       "width" => 20,
       "height" => 20,
       "marker_anchor" => [ 5, 10],
       "shadow_picture" => "/images/morgan.png" ,
       "shadow_width" => "110",
       "shadow_height" => "110",
       "shadow_anchor" => [5, 10],
      }
end
```

It describes in **Customize each marker** section. So try to put javascript in app/assets/javascripts/ and marker in app/assets/images/ folder.

Comment: basically its accessible from: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Gmaps4rails-before-v2